# CSV contains a sequence # the resets for different records, how to concat a specific column

Tags: csv, awk, sed

This is a bit convoluted, so bare with me.

I have a data file that I need to import into my company's software. I need to pre-process the CSV to make it into a format that is useable for me. I'm able to use linux or windows tools. The imports will eventually be automated so this pre-processing needs to be scriptable.

The CSV looks like:

```
Date,      Name,    ID,S#,Note
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,01,THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,02, DOG
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,01,THIS IS A NEW NOTE AND SHOULD NOT BE CO
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,02,NCATENATED WITH      THE PREVIOUS NOTE.
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,03,OOPS FORGOT A SPACE AFTER THE PERIOD
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,01,"TO ERR IS HUMAN TO FORGIVE IS DIVINE, B"
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,02,UT I THINK ERR IS SPELD WRONG AND I'LL 
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,03,NEVER FORGIVE THE QUOTE'S ARTHUR.
2020-01-01,Jane Doe,12,01,"NOTES CAN ALSO HAVE ""QUOTES"", WHICH EXTEN"
2020-01-01,Jane Doe,12,02,DS THEIR LENGTH
```

and it should be updated to:

```
Date,      Name,    ID,Note
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,THIS IS A NEW NOTE AND SHOULD NOT BE CONCATENATED WITH      THE PREVIOUS NOTE.OOPS FORGOT A SPACE AFTER THE PERIOD
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,"TO ERR IS HUMAN TO FORGIVE IS DIVINE, BUT I THINK ERR IS SPELD WRONG AND I'LL NEVER FORGIVE THE QUOTE'S ARTHUR."
2020-01-01,Jane Doe,12,"NOTES CAN ALSO HAVE ""QUOTES"", WHICH EXTENDS THEIR LENGTH"
```

The examples should be self explanatory. It's a CSV of notes that is split at 39 characters. Each time the sequence number (S#) resets to 01 it's a new note. The S# theoretically has no limit but in the data set I'm looking at it maxes out at 25. The Date, Name, and ID will be the same for each note.

I was initially going to use csvkit's csvsql (because SQL is normally my hammer, and this problem was looking like a nail to me). So I initially simply threw the CSV into a MSSQL* table to play around with it. Unfortunately my SQL skills weren't up to the challenge and I think I broke my brain when trying to figure out the logic to deal with the quotes.
*csvkit uses sqlite, so mssql was just for initial testing

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to a Python interpreter, you can leverage the `csv` module that properly solves every issue wrt unquoting and quoting your data.

For example, the following script

```python
from csv import reader, writer
from sys import stdout

# you may want
# data = open('./path/to/your_data_file')

data = '''\
Date,      Name,    ID,Note
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,01,THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,02, DOG
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,01,THIS IS A NEW NOTE AND SHOULD NOT BE CO
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,02,NCATENATED WITH      THE PREVIOUS NOTE.
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,03,OOPS FORGOT A SPACE AFTER THE PERIOD
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,01,"TO ERR IS HUMAN TO FORGIVE IS DIVINE, B"
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,02,UT I THINK ERR IS SPELD WRONG AND I'LL 
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,03,NEVER FORGIVE THE QUOTE'S ARTHUR.
2020-01-01,Jane Doe,12,01,"NOTES CAN ALSO HAVE ""QUOTES"", WHICH EXTEN"
2020-01-01,Jane Doe,12,02,DS THEIR LENGTH
'''.splitlines()

read_csv = reader(data)
write_csv = writer(stdout).writerow

old_s = 0
cache = []

first = next(read_csv) ; write_csv(first[:3]+first[4:])
for record in read_csv:
    s = int(record[3])
    if s<= old_s or old_s == 0: cache.append(record[:3])
    old_s = s
    cache[-1].append(record[-1])

for record in cache:
    write_csv(record[:3]+[''.join(record[3:])])
```

when run prints on the terminal the following

```
Date,      Name,    ID,Note
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,THIS IS A NEW NOTE AND SHOULD NOT BE CONCATENATED WITH      THE PREVIOUS NOTE.OOPS FORGOT A SPACE AFTER THE PERIOD
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,"TO ERR IS HUMAN TO FORGIVE IS DIVINE, BUT I THINK ERR IS SPELD WRONG AND I'LLNEVER FORGIVE THE QUOTE'S ARTHUR."
2020-01-01,Jane Doe,12,"NOTES CAN ALSO HAVE ""QUOTES"", WHICH EXTENDS THEIR LENGTH"
```

Comment: Thank you @gboffi, this answer is working properly with my lage data set.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a
     $!N
     /^(([^,]*,){3}).*\n\1/{
       /^(([^,]*,){4}).*\n\1/!s/("?)\n([^,]*,){4}(.*)/\3\1/
       ta}
     s/,(01|S#),/,/
     P
     D' file
```

Overview: The pattern space (the buffer on which sed operates) contains the current line and the next, separated by a newline (this is the effect of the `N` command). If the current line and the next line are part of the same record, the two are concatenated and the next line appended. This continues until either the records differ or the end of the file. Concatenation is determined by the key on each line. If the first three fields of the current and next line differ then the record can be released. Likewise, the keys of the first four fields are the same. Otherwise the first three fields are identical and the fourth must differ, hence concatenation.

N.B. The transfer of the `"` from end of the current line to end of the concatenated line. Also as all records begin `,01,` (or `S#` on the header) this can easily be removed before the record is published.

Comment: I tried and gave an error: sed: -e expression #1, char 39: Invalid back reference

Comment: @FábioAlmeida Oops, copy and paste can catch you out!. See edit.

Comment: Oops again! Missed the additional sequence field header, corrected,

Answer (score 1):

***program.awk***

```
NR == 1 {
    print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $5
}

NR == 2 {
    prevdate = $1
    prevname = $2
    previd = $3
    prevseq = int($4)
    prevnote = $5
}


NR > 2 {
    date = $1
    name = $2
    id = $3
    seq = int($4)
    note = $5
    if (prevseq >= seq) {
        gsub(/;;/,",", prevnote)
        if (prevnote ~ /^~/) {
            prevnote = prevnote dq
        }
        print prevdate "," prevname "," previd "," prevnote
        prevdate = date
        prevname = name
        previd = id
        prevseq = seq
        prevnote = note
    } else {
        gsub(/~$/,"",prevnote)
        prevnote = prevnote note
        prevseq = seq
    }
}

END {
    gsub(/;;/,",", prevnote)
    if (prevnote ~ /^~/) {
        prevnote = prevnote dq
    }
    print prevdate "," prevname "," previd "," prevnote
}
```

***execute:***

```
sed -r "s/\"/~/g" input.csv | awk -F",~" -v dq="~" ' { s= $2; if (s != "") { gsub(/,/,";;",s); s= dq s } print $1","s}' | awk -F"," -v dq="~" -f program.awk | sed -r "s/~/\"/g"
```

Comment: The first line should not be identical to the input. Where is the handling of quote extension?

Comment: I did not address this issue because I had doubts whether it was part of the problem. I will change to handling quotes.

Comment: Close but it is changing I'LL NEVER FORGIVE... to I"LL NEVER FORGIVE...

Comment: adjusted to handle single quotes

Answer (score 1):

Ruby comes with a CSV module. Here's a short program

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'csv'

out  = CSV.instance
data = CSV.read ARGV.shift
out << data.shift

current = nil
data.each do |record|
  if record[3] == "01"
    out << current if not current.nil?
    current = record
  else
    current[4] += " " if current[4].end_with? "."
    current[4] += record[4]
  end
end
out << current if not current.nil?
```

Then

```sh
ruby parse.rb file.csv
```

outputs

```
Date,      Name,    ID,S#,Note
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,01,THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,01,THIS IS A NEW NOTE AND SHOULD NOT BE CONCATENATED WITH      THE PREVIOUS NOTE. OOPS FORGOT A SPACE AFTER THE PERIOD
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,01,"TO ERR IS HUMAN TO FORGIVE IS DIVINE, BUT I THINK ERR IS SPELD WRONG AND I'LL  NEVER FORGIVE THE QUOTE'S ARTHUR."
2020-01-01,Jane Doe,12,01,"NOTES CAN ALSO HAVE ""QUOTES"", WHICH EXTENDS THEIR LENGTH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, ' $4==1{i++} {if(NR>1)$4=i}1 ' mrplow.txt | awk -F, ' NR==1{ print; next } $4!=pk { if(NR>2) print ks "," rs; pk=$4; ks=$1 "," $2 "," $3;rs="" } { $1=$2=$3=$4=""; gsub(/^[ ]{4}/,"",$0); rs=rs $0 }  END { print ks "," rs } '
Date,      Name,    ID,S#,Note
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,THIS IS A NEW NOTE AND SHOULD NOT BE CONCATENATED WITH      THE PREVIOUS NOTE.OOPS FORGOT A SPACE AFTER THE PERIOD
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,"TO ERR IS HUMAN TO FORGIVE IS DIVINE  B"UT I THINK ERR IS SPELD WRONG AND I'LL NEVER FORGIVE THE QUOTE'S ARTHUR.
2020-01-01,Jane Doe,12,"NOTES CAN ALSO HAVE ""QUOTES""  WHICH EXTEN"DS THEIR LENGTH
$
```

Explanation:

First awk introduces keys

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, ' $4==1{i++} {if(NR>1)$4=i}1 ' mrplow.txt
Date,      Name,    ID,S#,Note
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,1,THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,1, DOG
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,2,THIS IS A NEW NOTE AND SHOULD NOT BE CO
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,2,NCATENATED WITH      THE PREVIOUS NOTE.
2020-01-01,John Doe,50,2,OOPS FORGOT A SPACE AFTER THE PERIOD
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,3,"TO ERR IS HUMAN TO FORGIVE IS DIVINE, B"
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,3,UT I THINK ERR IS SPELD WRONG AND I'LL
2020-01-02,Jane Doe,45,3,NEVER FORGIVE THE QUOTE'S ARTHUR.
2020-01-01,Jane Doe,12,4,"NOTES CAN ALSO HAVE ""QUOTES"", WHICH EXTEN"
2020-01-01,Jane Doe,12,4,DS THEIR LENGTH
$
```

Second awk compares the keys and concatenates using prior values. Only first 4 spaces should be replaced in the sub function.